# Trouble with using Nginx with django and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx

I follow the steps in http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html but when all the steps done without any error I visit 127.0.0.1:8000, it response with a time-out, my nginx log shows that

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,

By the way, I can access 127.0.0.1:8001 where uwsgi and django works well.
And I can access image in 127.0.0.1:8000/image/1.jpg as well, but just cannot access 127.0.0.1:8000

here's my nginx.conf

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media {
        alias /home/zhaolei/virtualdjango/bin/mysite/media;
    }

    location /image {
        alias /home/zhaolei/virtualdjango/bin/mysite/image;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /home/zhaolei/virtualdjango/bin/mysite/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I use `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8001 --chdir=mysite --module=mysite.wsgi`
 to run uwsgi. I use `uwsgi_params` hosts in https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI have 2 protocols to communicate with web server. One of them is normal HTTP protocol, that can also be used to communicate directly with clients. But there is also special uwsgi protocol, optimized for communication between HTTP Proxy server and uWSGI.

That protocol is used by nginx when using `uwsgi_pass` directive, and by uWSGI when you're starting your uWSGI server with `--socket` param.

If you're starting uWSGI with `--http` param, uWSGI will use HTTP protocol (that is what you're doing), but if nginx is still using `uwsgi_pass` it's expecting uWSGI protocol on that socket, not HTTP.

To fix it you have to either change your uwsgi start command to use `--socket` instead of `--http` (that's recommended way, but you won't be able to check if uWSGI is functioning properly by entering `127.0.0.8001` directly in your browser, but that's okay: if your command with `--http` worked properly, there won't be any difference using `--socket`) or use `proxy_pass` instead of `uwsgi_pass` in your nginx config.

And it's described on link that you're mentioned, right [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py)

Comment: Thank you so much! It have bothered me for a whole night!