# django nginx setup issues

Tags: django, nginx

In the following i am trying to configure from http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

The following is my conf file  below placed in my project directory and have  linked the same in the sites-enabled of the nginx directory.

Now when i access my http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/files?path=/  i end up with `502 Bad Gateway` and the nginx error log says

`2015/09/21 14:07:41 [error] 8023#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "127.0.0.1:8000"`

but i am able to access this link http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/a.jpg what am i doing wrong here and how can access my django application

```
  # mysite_nginx.conf

  # the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
  upstream django {
      # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
      server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
  }

  # configuration of the server
  server {
      # the port your site will be served on
      listen      8000;
      # the domain name it will serve for
      server_name 127.0.0.1; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
      charset     utf-8;

      # max upload size
      client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

      # Django media
      location /media  {
          alias /home/rajeev/django-test/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
      }

      location /static {
          #alias /path/to/your/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
          alias /home/rajeev/django-test/mysite/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
      }

      # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
      location / {
          uwsgi_pass  django;
          include /home/rajeev/django-test/mysite/conf/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
      }
  }
```

Edit1: uwsgi_params file

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Comment: Show you uwsgi config

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with using Nginx with django and uwsgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492425/trouble-with-using-nginx-with-django-and-uwsgi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed one [point](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py) in this tutorial. Configuration of uWSGI for nginx is different than configuration for checking in browser if uWSGI is working not only by used port, but also by protocol.

When deploying uWSGI for nginx, `--http` should be replaced by `--socket`. By that change, nginx will understand properly output from your uWSGI server, but your browser won't.

Configuration for browser (to check if uWSGI is working) can work for nginx also, but you must use `proxy_pass` instead of `uwsgi_pass` in nginx, and using it is not recommended, uwsgi protocol is faster and better for communication between web server and uWSGI server.

Comment: uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py where is this be configured

Comment: but i dont have a test.py file what is to be replaced instead of this

Comment: Django `wsgi.py` file, located in `yourproject/yourapp/` directory.

Comment: @GwynBleidD, I may be late, but can you please elaborate your answer in more details, I have read it more than 20 times, but still few things in your answer are hard to digest, thanks in advance.